# XPages closing browser

Tags: xpages

I am maintaining an XPages project developed in-house and have a weird problem.  If the user starts at the “Home” page and drills down through categories to a specific record, i.e. record ID “9H4G7J”, which opens in a separate browser tab, then commences a change but then decides to exit without saving, by clicking on the “Exit” button a prompt states – “Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page? This document may contain unsaved changes” – and when the user clicks Okay the record tab closes and user presented with the previous browser tab with the location of the record drilled down to in the categories.  This is good this is what we want.

**BUT**, if the user, instead of drilling down, enters the record ID “9H4G7J” in the search facility on the “Home” screen, then commences a change and clicks Exit, The same prompt outlined above is shown but when the user clicks okay a second prompt is shown stating –“The webpage you are viewing is trying to close this window.  Do you want to close this window?” – and if the user clicks “Yes”, the browser closes entirely!!!  Can anyone explain why this would behave differently like this?

Here is the Java code;

```
private UIComponent createEventHandler(FacesContext context, 
     UIComponent parent, PageExpressionEvaluator evaluator) {
        XspEventHandler result = new XspEventHandler();
        result.setSubmit(false);
        result.setEvent("onclick");
      MethodBinding script = evaluator.createMethodBinding(result,
         "if (XSP._isDirty()){\n    if (confirm (\"Are you sure you want to navigate   
         away from this page?\" + \"\\n\" + \"\\n\" +\n    \"This document may contain 
         unsaved changes.\" + \"\\n\" + \"\\n\" +\n    \"Press OK to continue, or 
         Cancel to stay on the current page.\")){\n        window.close();\n    }else
         {\n        return false;\n    }\n} else {\n   window.close();\n}",
           null,null, null);
           result.setScript(script);
           return result;
         }
```

And here is the XPage “Edit” button source code;

```
<xp:button value="Exit" id="button2">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[if (XSP._isDirty()){
        if (confirm ("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" + "\n" 
        + "\n" + "This document may contain unsaved changes." + "\n" + "\n" +
         "Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.")){
          window.close();
          }else{
          return false;
          }
       } else {
         window.close();
       }]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wait!  Just examined this again and one difference is that when searching for a record ID and then clicking the record to open it - this time it DOES NOT open a new tab but instead record is shown in same Browser tab.

Answer (score 1):

When an application opens a new tab or new window the JavaScript call `window.close();` closes that tab or window. If you issue a close on the last window open, the browser closes. To see the effect: Open an additional tab with a new page open (dilbert.com is a good choice) and see the effect.

To make your application behavior consistent change the code to either always open (target=_blank) or never open a new tab/window

I personally hate if applications open new tabs for me. If I want a new tab I can hold the Ctrl key before clicking. But that's a question of taste and your users might like the auto new tab. Just make it consistent

Comment: Yes. Thanks stwissel. I have discovered that opening a record through a search does not open a new tab like locating the record by drilling down does. It is not my decision to have the record open in a new window\tab its the end users and someone else developed this application - I just have the task of maintaining it. I am now just trying to find out how to make the selected record open in a new tab\window.

Comment: add an attribute target="_blank" to the displayed link.

Comment: Discovered the XPage that does work the way we want uses a Function named tkDynamicViewPanelRowClick in a JS file which calls the window.open command.  Also the columns in the XPage that works are NOT contained within a dynamicViewPanel but an ordinary viewPanel.  The XPage I need to change DOES use a Dynamic View Panel and I have tried emulating how the above works but because there is no consistent column name I can't get it to work.  XPage to change the HTML source is says "href="routetonotesdocument;action=editDocument" class="xspLinkViewColumn">" - how can I make the link open a new page?

Comment: I have tried adjusting the "target" property of the dynamic view panel to be "_blank" and also the onColumnClick property to "window.open()" but neither of these work.